# PHP Division Float Value Issue

Tags: php, math, decimal

When I Try get remainder, It gives invalid value. I am trying to get remained of two decimal values and I get

> 3.4694469519536E-18

My Values are

```
 $x=0.1; $y=0.005;
```

I tried the following:

```
echo $ed = fmod(0.1,0.005);  OutPut:3.4694469519536E-18
echo $ed = ((floatval(0.1)) % (floatval(0.005)));
```

But getting

```
Warning: Division by zero
```

But Reality is 0.1 will be divide by 0.005 in **20** times. i.e. `0.1/0.005 = 20`

The same function returns correct value when I use `10%1 = 0`.

How can I get the exact remainder. ( I don't face the same issue in JQuery :) )

Check an Work Around: [PHP Division Float Value WorkAround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100581/php-division-float-value-workaround)

Comment: 3.47e-18 is zero-ish. You have basic floating point issues.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I cannot able to get ur point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` operator just works on integers, so it truncates your floats to integers and tries to do `0 % 0`, which results in a division by zero.

The only thing you can use is `fmod()`. The issue you face here is the typical floating point imprecision (the value is "nearly" zero). I'd consider to just ignore values smaller then 10^-15. There's no real alternative to this in PHP.

What you could try is doing the real division, then, with a bit of luck traces of the imprecision disappear. (like `round(0.1 / 0.005) === 0.1 / 0.005`)

Comment: So basically, rather than `x == 0`, you would do `abs(x) < 1e-15`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yep, you have to do such things when using floats.

Comment: @bwoebi What will happen, If i multiply 100 in both the sides and check the remained? is that a good practice. i.e. ((0.1*100)%(0.005*100)) ?

Comment: @TomPHP You have 0.005, so you'd need at least 200. And there's the issue, you can multiply (and you need to choose a number which always fits, what might not be the case…), but you'd even then might have issues…

Comment: @bwoebi So the conclusion was PHP cant do such calculations? in a straight way?

Comment: @TomPHP neither you can with C. You always can write your own Decimal number implementation (that's what Javascript has built-in), but generally no.

Comment: @bwoebi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100581/php-division-float-value-workaround