# PHP Division Float Value WorkAround

Tags: php, math, decimal

Kindly refer: [PHP Division Float Value Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038538/php-division-float-value-issue)

With reference to the Question I have wrote the following code. Can this be done in different way or less code than this.?

The following will help when any of the two given value are lesser than **1** with decimal values. Is this a good practice?

```
<?php

        $First_Value = 0.005;
        $Second_Value = 0.1;

        // Check the First Value for Decimal
        $First_Whole = floor($First_Value);  // 0
        $First_Fraction = $First_Value - $First_Whole; // .005

        // Check the Second Value for Decimal
        $Second_Whole = floor($Second_Value); // 0
        $Second_Fraction = $Second_Value - $Second_Whole; // .1

        // Multiply with 100 becaus ethe decimal is restricted to 3 digit so multiply with 100 works
        if(($First_Whole == 0) || ($Second_Whole == 0)){
            $First_Value = $First_Value*100; // 0.5
            $Second_Value = $Second_Value*100; // 10
        }

        echo $tableCount = $Second_Value / $First_Value; // 20
?>
```

Comment: If all of your values are restricted to three digits anyway, perhaps you could just store them as integers. Ex. Instead of having "12.345 dollars", have "12345 tenths of a cent".

Comment: @Kevin it differs with other money calculations?

Comment: Ok, so rewrite all your other money calculation functions to use tenths of a cent as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any of that calculation.  just do the last division.

```
...
$value1 = .005;
$value2 = .1;

echo $value1 / $value2;
```

results in 20

If you are trying to get just 2 decimals you can use number format after dividing.  If you are trying to format before dividing then you should still be able to number format.  If however, you cannot then why not just multiply both numbers by 1000 (three decimals) % by 1 and minus the difference of the mod from the actual.  that will give you 3 in this case, divide back by 1000

[EDIT]

to get the remainder do the following example

```
...
$v = .0055;
$d = .1;

$a = $d/$v;
$s = $a % ceil($a);
$r = $a - $s;
```

answer = .18181818181818181...

Comment: did u refereed??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038538/php-division-float-value-issue

Comment: The values are dynamic. so we cannot remove the '0' always.

Comment: there is no remainder when you divide .1 into .005 the answer is exactly 20.  now a register might not have an exact 0 figure as an extremely low number is the same as zero to the chip.  that's why its usually better to find a Zero in an if statement by saying less than 1 unless the interpreter is going to do that for you.

Comment: Check the reference link and can you apply your logic will it work?

Comment: updated the answer, is this what you are looking for?